# remove compound field according to subfield value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file contains compound fields of "A*B", where "A" and "B" are numerical values. I need a simple solution (like using one-line command of awk or sed) to remove fields with "B" higher than a specific value. For example, in the file I have

```
4*1 13*5 19*3 26*7 31*1 52*4 60*6 80*2
```

and I want to remove fields with "B" equal or higher than 5, so that the output will be

```
4*1 19*3 31*1 52*4 80*2
```

Comment: Excellent question, as I often have struggled with compound fields in awk (thanks for the phrasing!). Right now, there are only two 'dimensions' to split up text (in records and fields). Some hacks are sometimes possible, as in the accepted answer, where the record separator is misused, which only works if there is one line. I have also used `split` to solve different but related problems, but it would have been good to have a third dimension next to records and fields available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
awk -F'*' '$2<5' RS=' ' ORS=' ' file
```

Comment: very smart, thaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In awk you could try this:

```
awk -F" " '{s="";
            for(i=1; i <= NF; i++){
                split($i, a, "*");
                if(a[2] < 5){s = s $i (i == NF ? "\n" : " ")}
            }
           print s;
           }' inputFile
```

The output for the given example:

```
4*1 19*3 31*1 52*4 80*2
```

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ echo "4*1 13*5 19*3 26*7 31*1 52*4 60*6 80*2" 
| awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
           if($i~/[0-9]+\*[1-4]\y/) 
              printf "%s ", $i; 
        print ""}'

4*1 19*3 31*1 52*4 80*2
```

UPDATE:
using @anubhava's RS trick, much shorter.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} /[0-9]+\*[1-4]\y/'
```

edit: add word boundary.

Comment: Hmm what if input is `str='4*1 13*5 19*31 26*7 31*1 52*4 60*6 80*2'`

Comment: I am attracted by this solution, but how about the string being 4*1 13*5 19*31 26*13 31*11 52*28 60*6 80*2, and I want to remove fields with "B" >=13

Comment: eventually regex will get unmanageable, but for 13 you can change `[1-4]\y` to `([1-9]|1[0-2])\y`, reads as: either one digit or 10,11, or 12.